# How to test CLLocationManager using the iPhoneSimulator

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Is there anyway to test the navigation functionality in MonoTouch using the iPhone simulator? Or will I need to write a wrapper class with timer events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the current beta version you can simulate other positions as well. There are buttons in XCode to choose from some predefined positions or your own positions.
In the simulator there is a menu item called ***'Debug' -> 'Location'*** where you can choose your positions as well.
You should also be able to create a whole list of positions which are simulated.

While Debugging in XCode:

[image: Choose from different locations to simulate]

> **Location simulation**
>
> Now you can test your location-based features in your app without leaving your desk. You can now select from preset locations and routes within the iOS Simulator and pick a custom latitude and longitude with accuracy while you're running your simulated app.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about mono touch but I do know that in the simulator there is no way to test a locationManager without a wrapper class as you suggested. The delegate methods will never be called because the pseudo position is always fixed.